# (r) Error in `[.data.frame`(df, i:i) : undefined columns selected

Tags: r

```
    df <- data.frame(0=c('a','b','c','d'),
                 a=c(200,200,200,200),
                 b=c(20,20,20,20),
                 c=c(10,10,10,10),
                 d=c(100,100,100,100),
                 e=c(2,2,2,2),
                 f=c(50,50,50,50),
                 g=c(200,200,200,200),
                 h=c(20,20,20,20),
                 i=c(10,10,10,10),
                 j=c(200,200,200,200),
                 k=c(20,20,20,20),
                 l=c(10,10,10,10),
                 m=c(100,100,100,100),
                 n=c(2,2,2,2),
                 o=c(50,50,50,50),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

totals_list <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
i <- 2
for (sets in 2:ncol(df)){
  x <- colSums(df[i:i], na.rm = TRUE)
  i <- i + 1
  y <- colSums(df[i:i], na.rm = TRUE)
  i <- i + 1
  z <- round(x/y,2)
  i <- i + 1
  totals_list <- c(totals_list,x,y,z)
}

totals_list <- c("Totals", totals_list)
totals_df <- as.data.frame(totals_list, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
totals_df <- setNames(totals_df, names(df))
final <- rbind(df, totals_df)
print(final)
```

Getting this error:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(df, i:i) : undefined columns selected

Based off of other Stack Overflow answers, I tried `df[i:i, ]`

I can't find answers from other stack overflows as to how to fix this error. And all columns in both DFs are defined and match.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? If you can explain it, we might be able to help you. `df[i:i,]` is simply just `df[i,]`.

Comment: I'm trying to add a total/summary row to the bottom of the dataframe. The dataframe will always consists of column sets of three. The first col is summed, the second col is summed and the third col is divided. This is why I have to loop, keeping an index (i) number of what col I am on. Then I need to add the totals dataframe to the df dataframe. When I try df[i, ] my totals only consists of 1 obs and 1 var... it sohuld be 1 obs and 19 var. So that's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loop is executing 15 times. This results in `i` increasing up to 47 which is greater than the number of columns in `df`.

Change to a `while` loop which checks the value of `i`.

```
i <- 2
while (i + 2 <= ncol(df)) {
  x <- colSums(df[i], na.rm = TRUE)
  i <- i + 1
  y <- colSums(df[i], na.rm = TRUE)
  i <- i + 1
  z <- round(x / y,2)
  i <- i + 1
  totals_list <- c(totals_list, x, y, z)
}

totals_list <- c("Totals", totals_list)
totals_df <- as.data.frame(totals_list, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
totals_df <- setNames(totals_df, names(df))
final <- rbind(df, totals_df)
print(final)
#>       X0   a  b  c   d e  f   g  h  i   j  k  l   m n  o
#> 1      a 200 20 10 100 2 50 200 20 10 200 20 10 100 2 50
#> 2      b 200 20 10 100 2 50 200 20 10 200 20 10 100 2 50
#> 3      c 200 20 10 100 2 50 200 20 10 200 20 10 100 2 50
#> 4      d 200 20 10 100 2 50 200 20 10 200 20 10 100 2 50
#> 5 Totals 800 80 10 400 8 50 800 80 10 800 80 10 400 8 50
```

This can also be written like this.

```
totals <- colSums(df[-1])

every_third_index <- which(seq_along(totals) %% 3 == 0)
totals[every_third_index] <- totals[every_third_index - 2] / totals[every_third_index - 1]

rbind(df, c("Totals", totals))
#>       X0   a  b  c   d e  f   g  h  i   j  k  l   m n  o
#> 1      a 200 20 10 100 2 50 200 20 10 200 20 10 100 2 50
#> 2      b 200 20 10 100 2 50 200 20 10 200 20 10 100 2 50
#> 3      c 200 20 10 100 2 50 200 20 10 200 20 10 100 2 50
#> 4      d 200 20 10 100 2 50 200 20 10 200 20 10 100 2 50
#> 5 Totals 800 80 10 400 8 50 800 80 10 800 80 10 400 8 50
```